# Remover registos duplicados de uma tabela

Tags: sql, query

Tendo as seguintes tabelas sem chaves ainda definida:

Avião (codigo_aviao, código_companhia, ano, tipo_motor, tipo_avião, estado)

Voo ( Codigo_voo, Numero_voo, código_avião, código_companhia)

Em alguns casos, cerca de 400 registos da tabela avião, um avião está associado a duas companhias aéreas e eu não pretendo isso, pretendo que cada avião possua apenas uma companhia aérea. 
No seguinte cenário:

Código_avião | Código_companhia

N107AS       | AS

N107AS       | EV

O mesmo avião está associado a duas companhias aéreas diferentes. Acontece que na tabela Voo, quando se trata do avião N107AS existem 8000 registos para quando está associado à companhia AS e 1000 para a companhia EV.

O que pretendo é remover as companhias em que se verifiquem menos registos de forma a que cada avião tenha apenas uma companhia aérea e essa seja a que tem mais registos na tabela voo.

Isto para os 400 casos. Há alguma forma automatizada de o fazer ou terei que os apagar individualmente?

Comment: Você não tem(ou não conhece quem tenha) controle do sistema que gera esses dados? Porque talvez o correto seria corrigir como são gerados e não ficar excluindo duplicidades.

Comment: São dados já antigos e que se encontram em ficheiros csv. O objetivo não passa por análise de dados mas sim medir o desempenho de algumas bases de dados. Apenas me surgiu este conflito pois na minha tabela final vião o atributo  codigo_aviao deverá ser chave primária e dessa forma não dá. Ao mesmo tempo quero ter o máximo de registos possíveis na tabela voo

Comment: Tem como criar uma SQL que gere outra SQL que é exatamente o que você precisa, porém para isso vai ter que postar aqui a estrutura relacional dos modelos certinho. Se não fica impossível criar alguma solução para o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro será necessária uma consulta para retornar a quantidade de voos de um avião, agrupados por companhia:

```
select 
    v.cod_companhia t_comp, 
    count(v.cod_voo) as t_voo,
    v.cod_aviao as t_avi
  from 
    voo v
  where
    v.cod_aviao = 'N107AS'
  group by
    v.cod_companhia;
```

O resultado desta consulta será a quantidade de voos de um determinado avião, agrupados por companhia:

[image: resultado da consulta 1]

Tendo este resultado, incluiremos esta consulta dentro de uma nova consulta, que nos retornará a companhia que tem menos voo para este avião, dada a quantidade total de voos:

```
select t_comp, t_avi, min(t_voo)
from
  (select 
    v.cod_companhia t_comp, 
    count(v.cod_voo) as t_voo,
    v.cod_aviao as t_avi
  from 
    voo v
  where
    v.cod_aviao = 'N107AS'
  group by
    v.cod_companhia) g_voo;
```

[image: resultado da consulta 2]

Com o resultado desta consulta, já é possível determinar qual companhia tem menos voos com o determinado avião. A partir disto, é possível implementar uma instrução de `delete` baseado nesta consulta.

Não é a **solução**, mas pode ajudar a chegarmos numa.